# iOS: How can app extension copy file to app Documents/ folder?

Tags: ios, swift

In the app extension is there a way to get file and copy it to Documents// folder?

I can get file with the code below. But how to copy it? I alway have an error

```
        for item in self.extensionContext!.inputItems as! [NSExtensionItem] {
        for provider in item.attachments! as! [NSItemProvider]  {
            provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: provider.registeredTypeIdentifiers.first! as! String, options: nil, completionHandler: { (fileURL, error) in
                if let fileURL = fileURL as? URL {
                    self.url = fileURL
                    // self.extensionOpenUrl(App.associatedDomain + fileURL.absoluteString)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

copy by click:

```
 let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let pathForDocumentsDirectory = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: App.group)!.path

    let fileURL = self.url!
    let name = fileURL.lastPathComponent
    let copiedPath = pathForDocumentsDirectory
    do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: fileURL.absoluteString, toPath: copiedPath)
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: copiedPath) {
            print("fileExists!!!")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("error in copyItemAtPath")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

file url:

```
 file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/OutgoingTemp/3CEC8D4A-9B1B-468B-A919-7C70C9C522B3/IMG_5484.jpg
```

path to copy:

```
 /private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/D7D2317B-9C57-424D-9D2F-209C62BBFAE5/IMG_5484.jpg
```

error:

```
  The file “IMG_5484.jpg” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
```

Comment: Extensions are their own binaries with their own directory structure. If you want to share data between your extensions and host apps, you need to create an app group. [Relevant Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html)

Comment: @AndyIbanez i updated with code and error text, please check my answer. ALso, i have app groups..

Comment: At what point are you actually attempting the copy? Your code seems to break this up, storing the URL and later trying the copy. I think you’ll find you have to do the copy whilst the loadItem block is active and the file is actually available

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Extensions can communicate with the main app only by leaving/modifying the files in the App Group space (which means also that you must create the App Group first in the developer portal and add proper entitlements).

Comment: I updated with code and error text, please check my answer. ALso, i have app groups..

Answer (score 0):

The extension doesn't have access to the container app's document directory (or any directory of the main app for that matter). As someone already pointed out that you can setup an app group and copy the file to the app group shared dir, then the main app will have access to the file in the shared app group folder.

```
    func shareFileWithApp(_ url: URL) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if let urlGroup = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.myapp")?.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent) {
            
            // Write to Group Container
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: urlGroup.path) {                                        
                do {
                    try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: url.path, toPath: urlGroup.path)
                    return urlGroup
                } catch { print("Error copy file: \(error)")}
            }
            return urlGroup
   }
    return nil
  }
```

*group.myapp* should be your app group id. In the code, the `url` is the file url that you want to share from your extension to the main app. You probably also want to activate your main app once this is done so your main app can process/use the shared file depending on your app's logic.